# Using @UpdateTimestamp not working and error when using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I am using Spring and JPA and constructing an update query. It updates correctly. But I also want to update the time to current time stamp.

Initially wanted to just use @UpdateTimestamp over the timestamp field. It throws no error. The update happens for other columns but no change in the timestamp.

Code as follows:

The Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Column("name") 
    private String name;

    @MapsId("number")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NUMBER")
    private NumEntity numEntity;

    // this annotation makes no diff and date does not change
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "CREAT_TS")
    private Timestamp createdTimestamp;
}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, SomeClass> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE MyEntity e SET e.name =:name WHERE e.someClass.id =:id")
    void updt(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name);
}
```

Method making the update

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(int id, String name) {  
    myRepository.updt(id, name);
}
```

Alternatively I tried to make the time stamp update in the query itself as follows. This throws an error when I try to run myMethod. Please advice, ok with a solution for either scenarios. Thanks.

Error

> CAUSE=InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not
>   bound : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound :
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Repo using current timestamp in query.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, SomeClass> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE MyEntity e SET e.createdTimestamp =:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, e.name =:name WHERE e.someClass.id =:id")
    void updt(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name);
}
```

UPDATE:

Went back to using the timestamp annotation in the entity class as follows:

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "CREAT_TS")
private Timestamp createdTimestamp;
```

Instead of writing a custom query, using save to perform the update as advised in the comments.

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(SomeClass someClass, String name) {  
    MyEntity myEntity = myRepository.findById(someClass); // works
    myEntity.setName("david");
    myRepository.save(myEntity);
}
```

If myEntity's name field is already called "david" for this entity, nothing happens, no errors, no updates. If "david" is a new name (let's say previously name was Dan), only the timestamp gets updated but the name remains as "david". Anyone able to see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it is a named parameter and it is expecting a value as you are doing for other two named parameters `:name` and `:id`

Comment: @karvai can you show what Timestamp class you are importing?

Comment: You should be storing the entity for this to work, you are bypassing all of that by creating your own query. Retrieve the entity, set name, and persist.

Comment: @EamonScullion It is from package java.sql;

Comment: @SeshidharG I get that but isn't CURRENT_TIMESTAMP a built in name. Why would I need to pass that in?

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry could you elaborate. If I retrieve an entity, set name and do a .save() isn't that just gonna create a new row?

Comment: @karvai save will create or update depending on the id, if the ID already exists, it will update it

Comment: @M.Deinum Tested it out. If I retrieve an entity, set name and do a .save() I want the timestamp to update even if the entire entity didn't change. By doing your suggested method, the timestamp won't update.

Comment: @EamonScullion Got you, but this still will not work for what I am looking for. I want the timestamp to update even if nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, try with save method, it should be the method that triggers the timestamp to set

Comment: @EamonScullion Updated the query above. Please have a look.

Comment: If nothing changes, nothing will be persisted and thus nothing will be updated. Why should it be updated when nothing changes?

Comment: @karvai Yes, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a built in name and in your case it is working as a named parameter and you have to pass value to that named parameter.

you have to change your updt() method to

`
void updt(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name,@Param("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") Timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

`

and should call like

`
updt(1,"name",new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));

`